# Lucene 7 scoring vs Lucene 4

Tags: lucene

We had a Lucene 4 index. We successfully upgraded our index and our code to Lucene 7.7. Everything is working nicely. But when looking at the scores, we noticed that now we see large numbers like 57.24629, 51.479507 or 48.664692 but for the same search results we used to see 4.1282754 or 2.685965.

We do not have anything tricky like custom scorers or custom Similarity.

We would like to understand the difference between Lucene 7 and Lucene 4 for the scores. Not only the scores for Lucene 7 are larger numbers but some results have moved up or down in the ranking. I thought that the basic formula is the same. Has the basic TfIdf formula changed?

I see that Lucene 7 is using BM25Similarity. Could that be why? Can someone explain BM25Similarity to me?

I have tried using Explain, but the results just overwhelm me. Is there an easier way of making sense of the explainaition?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: There have been various changes to Lucene between 4.x and 7.7, [several of which](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_3/changes/Changes.html#older) may have affected how scoring works. But I think the best way to get more insight would be to look at 2 equivalent score explanations - for example, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68353136/12567365). If you can track down the relevant versions of [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases), that may be the easiest approach.

Comment: Great suggestions and info. Thank you @andrewjames